# Pandas DataFrame: Given conditions of multiple columns, do a specific operation with some other columns

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe

Given the pandas DataFrame:

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
points = [[True, False, False, 2, 4, 5, 0, 6, 8, 9, 3, 9],
 [False, True, False, 3, 6, 2, 8, 9, 3, 2, 3, 0],
 [False, False, True, 8, 1, 8, 3, 6, 8, 9, 3, 2]]
df = pd.DataFrame(points, columns= ['1isObj','2isObj','3isOb',
 'X_1','X_2','X_3','Y_1','Y_2','Y_3','S_1','S_2','S_3'])

print(df)

   1isObj  2isObj   3isOb  X_1  X_2  X_3  Y_1  Y_2  Y_3  S_1  S_2  S_3
0    True   False   False    2    4    5    0    6    8    9    3    9
1   False    True   False    3    6    2    8    9    3    2    3    0
2   False   False    True    8    1    8    3    6    8    9    3    2
```

Each row contains 3 points x,y cordnats and it's speed. And there will be one row each point is the objective. 
I need to find the fastest time for the other points to move to the objective.

For row 0: 
point 1 is the objective and is at (2,0), to find the time we first have to find the distance from 2 to 1 and from 3 to using distance formula:

```py
time_2 = np.sqrt(np.square(df['X_2']-df['X_1'])+np.square(df['Y_2']-df['Y_1']))/df['S_2']
```

to find the time it takes for 2 to travel to 1. and we do the same for 3 and 1 and take the minimum as `'MinTime'`
For row 1, it would be finding the time between 1 to 2, and 3 to 2.

Do this for all rows and, return it with the original data frame.

```py
def min_time(df):
    df['MinTime'] = #Some Operation
    return df
```

## QUESTION:

What would be a way of doing this that does not involve a For loop looping over all the rows, which is highly inefficient? 
I am working with more than 100k rows and the target point can change between row to row.

Answer (score 0):

You can create new columns in your dataframe and then take the min of those columns by row

```
df['time_2'] = np.sqrt(np.square(df['X_2']-df['X_1'])+np.square(df['Y_2']-df['Y_1']))/df['S_2']
df['time_3']= np.sqrt(np.square(df['X_3']-df['X_1'])+np.square(df['Y_3']-df['Y_1']))/df['S_3']

# Get the min between 'time_2' and 'time_3' for each row
df['MinTime']  = df[['time_2','time_3']].min(axis=1)
```

Comment: The thing is that I am working with 100k + rows of data, and the objective points can be different from row to row.